# How can I tell a subview to resize when its superview changes size?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I'm working on an iOS application that has a UIViewController whose view has a MapView as a subview. However, when I run the application and try to rotate the view in the simulator, it doesn't work as it should; it leaves a black box as shown:

[image: Original View]

[image: Rotated View]

How can I tell the MapView to resize along with its superview?

Comment: Do you have any constraints or autoresizing masks set up?  Your map needs to know how to resize itself when it's superview changes size

Comment: My MapView is a subview of the UIViewController's view. How can I tell the map how to resize itself when the superview changes size?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code

**ObjC**

```
yourMapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                               UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                               UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

**Swift**

```
yourMapView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleRightMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleBottomMargin]
```